# Enterprise Validation Block different rulsets for parent child classes

Tags: c#, .net, validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

Validation on property of child class does not work when I have 2 different rulesets for The parent and child.

This is the class code: Mytype is the parent and Person is the child

```
    [HasSelfValidation]
    public class MyType
    {
        [SelfValidation(Ruleset = "RulesetA")]
        [SelfValidation(Ruleset = "RulesetB")]
        public void DoValidate(ValidationResults results)
        {
        }

        [NotNullValidator(Ruleset = "RulesetA")]
        [ObjectValidator("RulesetA", Ruleset = "RulesetA")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }

    }

    public class Person
    {
        [NotNullValidator(Ruleset = "RulesetB")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the custom validator class to validate MyType class against all rulesets:

```
    public interface IValidator<T>
    {
        ValidationResults Validate(T target);
    }

    public class MyValidator : IValidator<MyType>
    {
        public ValidationResults Validate(MyType target)
        {
            return Validation.Validate(target, new string[] {"RulesetA", "RulesetB"});
        }
    }
```

And this is the test which fails: (IsValid should be set to False but it's True)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_return_false_when_validating_MyType_without_PersonApplying_GivenName()
    {
        //arrange
        var myType = new MyType()
                            {
                                Person= new Person()
                            };
        myType.Person.GivenName = null;

        //act
        MyValidator _validator = new MyValidator();
        var resultList = _validator.Validate(myType);

        //assert
        Assert.IsFalse(resultList.IsValid);
    }
```

Would you please help?

Comment: I think you should remove the `Ruleset = "RulesetA"` from the `[ObjectValidator]`. Just decorate that property with: `[ObjectValidator]`. This makes sure that the `Person` always gets validated.

Comment: no it's still failing :(

Comment: And when you add `[ObjectValidator("RulesetB", Ruleset = "RulesetB")]` (and `RulesetA`) to the `Person` property?

Comment: It works but my question is that why it's not working in my case even though I am validating against all rulesets: Validation.Validate(target, new string[] {"RulesetA", "RulesetB"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAB validates your object per ruleset and concatenates the validation results. This is what the `Validation.Validate` method looks like:

```
var resultsReturned = new ValidationResults();

foreach (string ruleset in rulesets)
{
    var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator(
        targetType, ruleset, source);

    foreach (var validationResult in validator.Validate(target))
    {
        resultsReturned.AddResult(validationResult);
    }
}

return resultsReturned;
```

In other words, a validation on an object is always performed on a single ruleset. Since the `ObjectValidator` is only decorated for `RulesetA`, the `Person` object will not get validated when running on `RulesetB`.